# Creating dummy variables from multiple strings in the same row

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that looks like this (Notice that a blank separates each product):

```
Client_ID      Purchase
121212         "Orange_Juice Lettuce"
121212         "Banana Bread "
230102         "Banana Apple"
230102         "Chicken"
121212         "Chicken Bread"
301450         "Grapes Lettuce"
...            ...
```

Now, i wish to know what product each person purchases, using a dummy variable for each item:

```
Client_ID    Apple    Banana    Bread    Chicken    Grapes    Lettuce    Orange_Juice
121212       0        1         1        1          0         1          1  
230102       1        1         0        1          0         0          0
301450       0        0         0        0          1         1          0
...          ...      ...       ...      ...        ...       ...        ...
```

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490190/transforming-levels-of-one-variable-into-other-variables) some weeks ago, but i didn't have several items in the same row, as is the case here. So i'm really lost. I tried to separate the items in multiple columns, but that was not ideal, since each purchase can have a different number of items (up to dozens as far as i know).

Any ideas on how to proceed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really need the final data in a data set? or do you want to display it like you listed above? If you broke down the data to one id and one purchase per obs...then you could use Proc Report and display the purchase items with the ACROSS option...without having to know the PURCHASE names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a flexible solution using PROC FREQ and PROC TRANSPOSE.  The SPARSE option gets you your zeros.  I assume you only want 1 or 0, hence the NODUPKEY sort; remove NODUPKEY (or remove the sort entirely) if you do want 2 for BREAD for the first ID.

First create a vertical dataset with one record per ID/Product (splitting Purchase into Products); then PROC FREQ that dataset so you have a dataset with 1/0 for each client/product combination; then transpose that using product as ID and count as VAR.

If you have any products that you want to guarantee show up as zero even if *nobody* has them, you should add a row to the initial table (or anything prior to the proc freq) with a dummy client ID and ALL possible products, then after the transpose delete the dummy client ID.

```
data test;
input @1 Client_ID  6.   @16 Purchase $50.;
datalines;
121212         Orange_Juice Lettuce
121212         Banana Bread 
230102         Banana Apple
230102         Chicken
121212         Chicken Bread
301450         Grapes Lettuce
;;;;
run;

data vert;
set test;
format product $20.;
do _x = 1 by 1 until (missing(product));
  product=scan(purchase,_x);
  if not missing(product) then output;
end;
run;
proc sort data=vert nodupkey;
by client_id product;
run;

proc freq data=vert;
tables client_id*product/sparse out=prods;
run;

proc transpose data=prods out=horiz;
by client_id;
id product;
var count;
run;
```

Comment: This solution is perfect! Thanks a lot, @Joe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a data step programming solution:

```
proc sort data=have;
   by client_id;
run;
data want(keep=client_id apple banana bread chicken grapes lettuce orange_juice);
   set have;
      by client_id;
   retain apple banana bread chicken grapes lettuce orange_juice;
   if first.client_id then do;
      apple = 0;
      banana = 0;
      bread = 0 ;
      chicken = 0;
      grapes = 0;
      lettuce = 0;
      orange_juice = 0;
      end;
   length item $20;
   _x = 1;
   item = scan(purchase,_x);
   do while(item ne ' ');
      select(item);
         when('Apple') then apple = 1;
         when('Banana') then banana = 1;
         when('Bread') then bread = 1;
         when('Chicken') then chicken = 1;
         when('Grapes') then grapes = 1;
         when('Lettuce') then lettuce = 1;
         when(("Orange_Juice') then orange_juice = 1;
         otherwise;
         end;
      _x = _x + 1;
      item = scan(purchase,_x);
      end;
   if last.client_id then output;
run;
```

**EDIT:** I missed the part of the question on more than one item in each `PURCHASE` variable.  Thanks Joe!

Answer (score 0):

It is also a workable solution to let the SAS data step do some of the dummy variable coding for you.

```
data test;
input Client_ID 6. Purchase $50.;
datalines;
121212         Orange_Juice Lettuce
121212         Banana Bread 
230102         Banana Apple
230102         Chicken
121212         Chicken Bread
301450         Grapes Lettuce
 ;;;;
 run;

filename tmp temp;
 data _null_;
 set test end = done;
 file tmp;
 length product $25 prodlist $1000;
 retain prodlist;
 do i = 1 to countw( purchase, " " );
      product = scan( purchase, i, " " );
      prodlist = ifc( indexw( prodlist, product )=0, catx( ' ', prodlist, product ), prodlist );
 end;
 if done then do; 
    prodlinit=prxchange("s/ /=0; /",-1,compbl(prodlist)); 
    put 'array prods(*) ' prodlist ';'  / prodlinit;
 end;
 run;

 data new;
  set test;
   %inc tmp/source2;
   do i = 1 to dim( prods );
     if indexw(purchase,vname(prods(i))) > 0 then prods(i) = 1;
   end; 
  run;

proc print;
run;
```