# SAS: Creating dummy variables from categorical variable

Tags: sas

I would like to turn the following long dataset:

```
data test;
input Id Injury $;
datalines;
1         Ankle
1         Shoulder 
2         Ankle
2         Head
3         Head
3         Shoulder
;
run;
```

Into a wide dataset that looks like this:

```
ID  Ankle Shoulder Head
1   1     1        0
2   1     0        1
3   0     1        1'
```

This answer seemed the most relevant but was falling over at the proc freq stage (my real dataset is around 1 million records, and has around 30 injury types):
[Creating dummy variables from multiple strings in the same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281626/creating-dummy-variables-from-multiple-strings-in-the-same-row)

Additional help: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Statistical-Procedures/Possible-to-create-dummy-variables-with-proc-transpose/td-p/235140

Thanks for the help!

Comment: One million records in a long format should be trivial for SAS. Can you explain how it 'fell over'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic method that should work easily, even with several million records. 
First you sort the data, then add in a count to create the 1 variable. Next you use `PROC TRANSPOSE` to flip the data from long to wide. Then fill in the missing values with a 0. This is a fully dynamic method, it doesn't matter how many different Injury types you have or how many records per person. There are other methods that are probably shorter code, but I think this is simple and easy to understand and modify if required.

```
data test;
input Id Injury $;
datalines;
1         Ankle
1         Shoulder 
2         Ankle
2         Head
3         Head
3         Shoulder
;
run;

proc sort data=test;
by id injury;
run;

data test2;
set test;
count=1;
run;

proc transpose data=test2 out=want prefix=Injury_;
by id;
var count;
id injury;
idlabel injury;
run;

data want;
set want;
array inj(*) injury_:;

do i=1 to dim(inj);
    if inj(i)=. then inj(i) = 0;
end;

drop _name_ i;
run;
```

Comment: This answer is perfect, genius in it's simplicity!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution involving only two steps... Just make sure your data is sorted by id first (the injury column doesn't need to be sorted).

First, create a macro variable containing the list of injuries

```
proc sql noprint;  
  select distinct injury  
    into :injuries separated by " "  
    from have  
    order by injury;  
quit;
```

Then, let `RETAIN` do the magic -- no transposition needed!

```
data want(drop=i injury);
  set have;
  by id;

  format &injuries 1.;
  retain &injuries;
  array injuries(*) &injuries;

  if first.id then do i = 1 to dim(injuries);
    injuries(i) = 0;
  end;

  do i = 1 to dim(injuries); 
    if injury = scan("&injuries",i) then injuries(i) = 1;
  end;

  if last.id then output;
run;
```

### EDIT

Following OP's question in the comments, here's how we could use codes and labels for injuries. It could be done directly in the last data step with a `label` statement, but to minimize hard-coding, I'll assume the labels are entered into a sas dataset.

1 - Define Labels:

```
data myLabels;
  infile datalines dlm="|" truncover;
  informat injury $12. labl $24.;
  input injury labl;
  datalines;
S460|Acute meniscal tear, medial
S520|Head trauma
;
```

2 - Add a new query to the existing `proc sql` step to prepare the label assignment.

```
proc sql noprint;  

  /* Existing query */
  select distinct injury  
    into :injuries separated by " "  
    from have  
    order by injury;

  /* New query */
  select catx("=",injury,quote(trim(labl)))
    into :labls separated by " "
    from myLabels;
quit;
```

3 - Then, at the end of the `data want` step, just add a `label` statement.

```
data want(drop=i injury);
  set have;
  by id;

  /* ...same as before... */

  * Add labels;
  label &labls;
run;
```

And that should do it!

Comment: Rather than the second do loop consider using a temporary array and then the WHICHC function. You can use the quote function within the first SQL step to get quoted list. Also...what if the injury has spaces in it, eg broken arm?

Comment: Replacing `injury` by `prxchange("s/[', ]/_/", -1, strip(injury))` in both the first and second step should take care of the variable names issue. I don't really see your point re: using `whichc` and additional array...

Comment: Is there a way to easily assign labels to columns using this method? I might use an injury code, say 'S460.' and assign a label for the variable 'Acute meniscal tear, medial'. This is easily done using the proc transpose method with 'idlabel'.